# Why is this photo over-rotated?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

This project takes 2 photos. One from AVCam and another from UIImagePickerController.

The photos are uploaded to an i/3 stream.

[image]

The photos from UIImagePickerController are flipping orientation when a full-size version of the photo is viewed, even though their orientation is correct on the i/3 stream.

[image]

The photos from AVCam are shown correctly both in their thumbnail version and full-size but the photos from UIImagePickerController are not.

`PhotoView.m`

```
    //Initialize
    //Lists photos according to the paramaters below
    self.tag = [[data objectForKey:@"IdPhoto"] intValue];
    
    int row = i/3;//set to 6 stream continues etc
    int col = i % 3;
    
    self.frame = CGRectMake(22.0*kPadding+col*(kThumbSide+kPadding), 560.5*kPadding+row*(kThumbSide+kPadding), kThumbSide, kThumbSide); //x = space left y = space down
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
...

//Load the image
    API* api = [API sharedInstance];
    
    int IdPhoto = [[data objectForKey:@"IdPhoto"] intValue];
    
    NSURL* imageURL = [api urlForImageWithId:[NSNumber numberWithInt: IdPhoto] isThumb:YES];
    
    AFImageRequestOperation* imageOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL] success:^(UIImage *image)
    {
        
        //create an image view, add it to the view
        UIImageView* thumbView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
        thumbView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,90,90);//thumbsize of image 180 is width and size 0 is spacing coordinates x,y
        thumbView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        //Rotates The Photo 180 Degrees
        thumbView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.5);
        [self insertSubview: thumbView belowSubview: caption];
        
    }];
```

`PhotoScreen.m`

```
#pragma mark - Image picker delegate methods
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
// Resize the image from the camera
UIImage *scaledImage = [image resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill bounds:CGSizeMake(photo.frame.size.width, photo.frame.size.height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
// Crop the image to a square 
UIImage *croppedImage = [scaledImage croppedImage:CGRectMake((scaledImage.size.width -photo.frame.size.width)/200, (scaledImage.size.height -photo.frame.size.height)/200, photo.frame.size.width, photo.frame.size.height)];
// Show the photo on the screen
photo.image = croppedImage;

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

photo.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.5);

}
```

I tried rotating the `imagePickerController` photo after it is taken and set to `photo` using `photo.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.5);` The transformation works, as without it, the photo is flipped on its side before being uploaded to the stream. But when an image is tapped to view in fullscreen, it always shows on its side.

```
// UIImage+Resize.m

#import "UIImage+Resize.h"
#import "UIImage+RoundedCorner.h"
#import "UIImage+Alpha.h"

@implementation UIImage (Resize)

// Returns a copy of this image that is cropped to the given bounds.
// The bounds will be adjusted using CGRectIntegral.
// This method ignores the image's imageOrientation setting.
- (UIImage *)croppedImage:(CGRect)bounds {
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], bounds);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
return croppedImage;
}

// Returns a copy of this image that is squared to the thumbnail size.
// If transparentBorder is non-zero, a transparent border of the given size will be added around the edges of the thumbnail. (Adding a transparent border of at least one pixel in size has the side-effect of antialiasing the edges of the image when rotating it using Core Animation.)
- (UIImage *)thumbnailImage:(NSInteger)thumbnailSize
      transparentBorder:(NSUInteger)borderSize
           cornerRadius:(NSUInteger)cornerRadius
   interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
UIImage *resizedImage = [self resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
                                                   bounds:CGSizeMake(thumbnailSize, thumbnailSize)
                                     interpolationQuality:quality];

// Crop out any part of the image that's larger than the thumbnail size
// The cropped rect must be centered on the resized image
// Round the origin points so that the size isn't altered when CGRectIntegral is later invoked
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(round((resizedImage.size.width - thumbnailSize) / 2),
                             round((resizedImage.size.height - thumbnailSize) / 2),
                             thumbnailSize,
                             thumbnailSize);
UIImage *croppedImage = [resizedImage croppedImage:cropRect];

UIImage *transparentBorderImage = borderSize ? [croppedImage transparentBorderImage:borderSize] : croppedImage;

return [transparentBorderImage roundedCornerImage:cornerRadius borderSize:borderSize];
}

// Returns a rescaled copy of the image, taking into account its orientation
// The image will be scaled disproportionately if necessary to fit the bounds specified by the parameter
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize interpolationQuality: (CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
BOOL drawTransposed;
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

// In iOS 5 the image is already correctly rotated. See Eran Sandler's
// addition here: http://eran.sandler.co.il/2011/11/07/uiimage-in-ios-5-orientation-and-resize/

if ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0 ) 
{
    drawTransposed = NO;  
} 
else 
{    
    switch ( self.imageOrientation ) 
    {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            drawTransposed = YES;
            break;
        default:
            drawTransposed = NO;
    }
    
    transform = [self transformForOrientation:newSize];
} 

return [self resizedImage:newSize transform:transform drawTransposed:drawTransposed interpolationQuality:quality];
}

// Resizes the image according to the given content mode, taking into account the image's orientation
- (UIImage *)resizedImageWithContentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode
                              bounds:(CGSize)bounds
                interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
CGFloat horizontalRatio = bounds.width / self.size.width;
CGFloat verticalRatio = bounds.height / self.size.height;
CGFloat ratio;

switch (contentMode) {
    case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill:
        ratio = MAX(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
        break;
        
    case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
        ratio = MIN(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
        break;
        
    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Unsupported content mode: %d", contentMode];
}

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width * ratio, self.size.height * ratio);

return [self resizedImage:newSize interpolationQuality:quality];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Private helper methods

// Returns a copy of the image that has been transformed using the given affine transform and scaled to the new size
// The new image's orientation will be UIImageOrientationUp, regardless of the current image's orientation
// If the new size is not integral, it will be rounded up
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize
            transform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
       drawTransposed:(BOOL)transpose
 interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
CGRect transposedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newRect.size.height, newRect.size.width);
CGImageRef imageRef = self.CGImage;

// Fix for a colorspace / transparency issue that affects some types of 
// images. See here: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/comment-page-2/#comment-39951
    
CGContextRef bitmap =CGBitmapContextCreate( NULL,
                                           newRect.size.width,
                                           newRect.size.height,
                                           8,
                                           0,
                                           CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ),
                                           kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast );

// Rotate and/or flip the image if required by its orientation
CGContextConcatCTM(bitmap, transform);

// Set the quality level to use when rescaling
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, quality);

// Draw into the context; this scales the image
CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, transpose ? transposedRect : newRect, imageRef);

// Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

// Clean up
CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(newImageRef);

return newImage;
}

// Returns an affine transform that takes into account the image orientation when drawing a scaled image
- (CGAffineTransform)transformForOrientation:(CGSize)newSize {
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationDown:           // EXIF = 3
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:   // EXIF = 4
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.width, newSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;
        
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:           // EXIF = 6
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:   // EXIF = 5
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;
        
    case UIImageOrientationRight:          // EXIF = 8
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:  // EXIF = 7
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, newSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:     // EXIF = 2
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:   // EXIF = 4
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;
        
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:   // EXIF = 5
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:  // EXIF = 7
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.height, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

return transform;
}

@end
```

Can someone help me parse through UIImage+Resize.m to see if anything can be done when viewing the full image for the photos taken with UIImagePickerController?

**Edit** I know we probably can flip the images on the StreamPhotoScreen that views the photos full size, but that would flip the other image orientations as well.

Comment: Isn't `M_PI*0.5` 90 degrees?

Comment: yes. it is 90 degrees.

Comment: I used it twice so far. Once on the entire `i/3` photo stream, because it was loading over-rotated 90 degrees. And the second time on `PhotoScreen` so that the picture that UIImagePickerController takes has a correct orientation after it sets the captured image to `photo` because after it is taken and set to photo, it is also over rotated without explicitly rotating it.

Comment: I think the photo taken with UIImagePickerController will also have orientation data in it. So you have to take into account that data when displaying.

Comment: What's the best way to display it considering the fact that the AVCam photos also are displayed in a full-size version? I don't want to rotate the full-size images because then the AVCam photos will be on their side most likely.

Comment: @GeneCode do you see anything that might work?

Comment: I expect the images to be JPEG, can you confirm there is no rotation set in the image metadata https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html